# Sort each line in different sequence

Tags: java

It is just curious how can I sort each line **(int type)** (which is stored in 2-dimensional array) in different order , for example I have `numbers[][]` and then the first line in my `numbers[1][]` will be sorted in `asc order`, then next line should be sorted in `dec order` and so on.

I have already tried `bubble algorithm` by swapping my elements with each other (I use condition if my index % 2 ==0) then I make asc order else I make dec order, and it works. *This style was not very elegant and demand 3 for loops*. But is there any other way to achieve this? (Sorting speed does not matter now)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Integer[][] array = new Integer[2][3];

Arrays.sort(array[0]);
Arrays.sort(array[1], Collections.reverseOrder());
```

You could use a loop to go through all the lines.

**EDIT**

Be careful about `Collections.reverseOrder()` though, this will only work on **non-primitive** types! If you want to use it for primitve type arrays you can use `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(myArray))` to reverse the array and then sort it in ascending order as shown above.

Comment: You can also use `ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)` from `Commons.Lang`

Comment: Thanks it helps. I am not using Wrapper classes, so maybe I should use anonymous class Comparator to make it?

Comment: @solvator Either you write your own Comparator or you use the second part of my answer or the comment from ZouZou.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the sorting algorithm yourself?

If not you can use:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers[1]);
```

Comment: How does it sort ascending and descending?

Comment: No, it is not important. Your way is not approriate, because I have separated values in my array for example:

numbers[1][1] = 1;
numbers[1][1] = 2;

and so on

Comment: It is sorting by bubble method. I sort 2 dimensional array;

Comment: It sorts as you wanted. And for descending order see Octoshapes answer

Comment: Yes, now I get it! Until now I only needed to sort 1 dimension array and then I got 2-dimension array I am a little bit confused and fit old style by using bubble method. Thanks!!